# Amazon SES : customize verification email HTML

Tags: amazon-ses

Our customer need to validate their email to uses amazon SES.
The problem is that the email is a bulk of english text and not very user friendly.

The docs does not state a way to customize the confirmation email sent from amazon. 
Is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Verifying the email address is a one-time thing, so if they can't find someone to read it/translate it for them, perhaps verifying the entire domain might be a better option?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html

This does require access to their dns settings however, i.e. in route 53, but is quite easy to do for them if you have such access.

Comment: This solution is a workaround, but our client does not have access to their DNS configuration. Customize the validation email should be simple I don't get why amazon didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it wasn't available in the past, but amazon let's you change the e-mail template used when sending verification links to customers by providing a template. [See documentation here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-verification-emails.html)

You can have up to 50 custom templates. Then, using the SDK of your choice, you would call the `SendCustomVerificationEmail`. [See documentation here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendCustomVerificationEmail.html)